# Take each first element from sub-groups ordered by a second column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data that has been ordered by two columns looks like:

```
X | Y
--+---
A | 4  
A | 2  
A | 0  
B | 3  
B | 2  
B | 1
```

And I want to structure my SQL query so that it would output:

```
X | Y
--+---
A | 4  
B | 3
```

Any tips?

```
SELECT
    table1.X, 
    max(table2.Y)
FROM 
    table1
INNER JOIN 
    table2
ON table1.X = table2.X
ORDER BY 
    table1.X, 
    table2.Y DESC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `ROW_NUMBER` like this:

```
SELECT
    x, y
FROM (
    SELECT 
        t1.x, t2.y,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.x ORDER BY t1.x, t2.y DESC) as seq
    FROM
        table1 t1
        JOIN 
        table2 t2 ON t1.x = t2.x) t
WHERE
    (seq = 1)
```

The `seq` is sorted over `t1.x` and `t2.y DESC` and resets  by changing `t1.x`.

Comment: This ended up working really well with another filter I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no concept of "first" row in a group, unless a column specifies the ordering.

From you sample data, though, a simple `max()` would suffice to get the desired results:

```
select x, max(y)
from table t
group by x;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. So it seems like that should work, but I've provided a code sample above to show whats actually going on. Adding the max() as suggested gives the error "not a single-group group function"

Comment: @JakeSpracher. . . You need to include `group by x` in your query.